# Cannot Start another activity after click the Button (android)

Tags: java, android

I cannot start my activity (Display Message) when I click the button that show in activity_main.xml. I have try fix the problem in onClick but still cannot Run it. Can I know what is the problem ? Thank You.

Here are the code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public Button but1;

    public void init(){
        but1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent display = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessage.class);

                startActivity(display);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.products));

        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="358dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:text="Confirm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Call init() in oncreate after setContentView

Comment: Thk You, it work for me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you never called `init()` from your `onCreate()` method. Therefore, `but1` was never initialized and `OnClickListener` was never set.